# Passing std::unique_ptr to a function by using a variable that is already created using new X()

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I am new to C++ and have some confusion regarding what happens in the following 2 scenarios.

1. I create the variable using new key word and then pass that variable as std::unique_ptr<>(x) to a function. When I do this, I can still access this->handler_ from the class that I passed.

Note: Y is the super class of X

```cpp
this->handler_ = new X(this);
auto res1 = root()->grpcStreamHandler(std::unique_ptr<Y>( this->handler_));
```

2. Create the variable as a unique pointer and pass it directly.

Note: Y is the super class of X

```cpp
this->handler_ = std::unique_ptr<Y>(new X(this));
auto res1 = root()->grpcStreamHandler(std::unique_ptr<Y>( std::move(handler_)));
```

For the 2nd case I know the `std::move()` moves the object and transfers the ownership to the function that we passed. But what's actually happening in the 1st case ? Would really appreciate if someone can explain clearly since I'm not very proficient in C++. Thanks

Comment: Yeah. I don't understand why I can still access the handler in the 1st case, even though I pass it like a std::unique_ptr().

Comment: How is `handler_` declared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, `this->handler_` ends up containing a pointer that it does not own (the `unique_ptr` owns it, and will `delete` it when the `unique_ptr` is destroyed unless it's extracted from the `unique_ptr` manually). If anything tries to `delete this->handler_` (e.g. what the destructor would do normally on reasonable classes with pointer members) you're double-freeing memory (undefined behavior), or if they try to use it after the `unique_ptr` cleans it, you're accessing freed memory (also undefined).

Basically, option #1 is almost certainly wrong, and even when it's not wrong, it's the worst sort of code smell (a pointer you allocate and store as an instance attribute, and don't `delete`? *shudders*). You want option #2, or more precisely, a simpler version of it:

```
auto res1 = root()->grpcStreamHandler(std::move(handler_));
```

that avoids explicitly constructing the new `unique_ptr` passed to the method when it would be move-constructed anyway. And really, you probably don't *want* `this->handler_` at all if all you're doing is immediately moving from it, just do:

```
auto res1 = root()->grpcStreamHandler(std::unique_ptr<Y>(new X(this)));
```

and construct/pass it as a single action (which may be able to elide the move).

Comment: Actually what I want is a shared_ptr here. Both of the class should be able to use the handler_. (One class asks the handler to send messages and other class makes callbacks when a message is received).  But the method grpcStreamHandler() takes a unique_ptr. So I'm out of options. Any recommended way ?

Comment: @LahiruUdayanga: Do you have any lifetime guarantees on the `unique_ptr`? Is it accessible as an attribute of the object returned by `grpcStreamHandler` perhaps?

Comment: As soon as the unique_ptr gets destroyed, I can send a callback to this class and let this class know that handler_ is destroyed.

Comment: @LahiruUdayanga: Okay, if you register that callback and it nulls out the `handler_`, that's not completely unreasonable (assuming simultaneous access to the object isn't an issue). I'd definitely comment the code creating it and the destructor (that fails to clean it) to ensure no eager beavers add a manual `delete` though. It's ugly/code smell, but if you're handcuffed by the framework, so be it.

Comment: No concurrent access. This is all single threaded. Yeah that's the way to go. Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, an unique_ptr instance is created and the allocated memory starts to be managed by its lifetime, i.e. an implicit ownership transfer occurs.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, `this->handler_` is a pointer, and the `unique_ptr` assumes ownership of the object that `this->handler_` points to.
The old pointer is valid until that object is destroyed, in the regular way.
You are not allowed to pass the pointer to `delete` unless the object's owner `release`s it.

In the second case, `this->handler_` represents an object with unique but transferrable ownership.
After you have transferred ownership by moving it to a new owner, the original owner has nothing.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, you're constructing a `std::unique_ptr` using a raw pointer.

In that case, *you are transferring the ownership of the pointer to the unique_ptr by constructing it*. RAII stands for **R**esource **A**quisition **I**s **I**nitialization. You initialize the unique pointer with a pointer to be owned, that unique pointer is responsible to clean it.

After calling the function, `this->handler_` is a non-null pointer to a potentially destroyed object.

I would advise alaways using the second case, or even better (if you have C++14):

```
this->handler_ = std::make_unique<X>(this);
auto res1 = root()->grpcStreamHandler(std::move(this->handler_));
```

The make unique function will take care of newing the object.

Comment: I wouldn’t say „destroyed”, the function can transfer the pointer someplace else. For sure the raw pointer carries no information about pointed object’s lifetime.

Comment: Yeah so what i'm trying to do here initiate a gRPC stream and send some messages through it. The class which I'm calling these should be able to access the handler_ even after calling grpcStreamHandler(). But that method takes a std::unique_ptr as a parameter. So the only way that works for me is the method 1. But as you said if the unique_ptr gets destroyed , I wouldn't know it and maybe call handler->send() . Any ideas ?